# How can I use the same chromedriver in multiple stepDefPages for multiple scenarios and without restarting my driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I want to do test on my application, so first scenario is the authentification, once done, i need to make test on the next page which is the home page, so how can i use the same driver without restarting my driver in the second scenario ? I want to start directly from : @given I'm on the home page!

I have a class for stepdefauthentification, another one for stepdefSearchCustomer, so how can i use my driver from the first class in the second ? The initialisation of the chromedriver is in the first page, and i can't even restart my driver by doing : driver.geturl("") in the second  because we need to authentify first so that the home page will display .

which means i need to recuperate the driver with it's url from the first scenario and then start from there in the second one .

Comment: Hope this helps..please check this link 'https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/36177'

Comment: One scenario should not depend on another, that's against cucumbers ideology. As of preserving webdriver instance, make web driver static, use singleton holder pattern.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732919/how-do-i-close-and-quit-selenium-driver-without-affecting-other-steps-in-cuc/55734156#55734156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your scenarios should NOT depend on each other, your scenarios should be autonomous, before ruining particular scenario, you should prepare all the conditions it needs to execute it, and preferably, clear after scenario as well.
2. To preserve browser window for multiple scenarios, make your WebDriver instance static, you can use Singleton Holder pattern for example.

I understand your issue, to test main page, you need to be logged in, so naturally you might think that executing scenarios in order would solve it, but its bad approach.

Instead, to test main page, either load cookies into web driver so it thinks that you are already logged into the session, or alternatively, you can create *'before'* ***@Login*** hook that can check, if you are logged in, if not it would run login procedure, before running scenario.

```
@Before(value = "@Login")
public void loginIfNeeded()
{
    // check you are logged in, if you are, do not login
    // if you are not logged in, perform login procedure.
}
```

***Sample scenario:***

```
@Login
Scenario: Test main page
  Given something
  When something
  Then something
```

Comment: as i am new in testing with cucumber and selenium i didn't knew that a scenario can't depend on another so Thank you.
So how can i test if i'm logging in or not, because at the first step i have to lunch the browser so i have to do **driver.geturl("")** so it's gonna take me to the authentification page ! how can i verify if i'm logging in or not pls

Comment: I gave you possible solutions for this issue, easiest one in my opinion is using hooks (gave you exact usage in my post) hooks let you execute certain code before/after scenario, in this case I used Before hook, and inside hook implementation you can first check if user is currently logged (just see if user is on the main page) if not - execute code responsible for login procedure.

Comment: And to verify if you are logged in, just try to locate some web element that is available only in the main page (but not in the login page) for example some welcome message etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use qaf which does driver and resource management. 
Your gherkin file will remain same. To [run your gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html) file use `GherkinScenarioFactory`

You can specify browser to use using `driver.name` [property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html). You don't need to write code for creating or tearing down driver. You can set behavior of driver session by using `selenium.singletone` property.

```
#this will tear down driver after each testcase/scenario
selenium.singletone=method
```

```
#this will tear down driver after each group and will reuse same driver session for testcases/scenario which are in same group.
selenium.singletone=group
```

```
#this will tear down driver after each xml test node in configuration file and will reuse same driver session for testcases/scenario configured under same xml test node.
selenium.singletone=test
```

```
#this will tear down driver after each xml suite node in configuration file.
selenium.singletone=suite
```